# jquery mosaic img show and hide

Tags: jquery, image, hide, thumbnails, mosaic

Hi and thanks in advanced, i want to create the effect in this site: http://www.bbdo.com/#!&pageid=0&subsection=4&itemid=-1 when you click any video of the thumbnail, it appears a new section and the video is displayed in a bigger size, i want to do this with images instead. I've been thinking in using some .hide() and .show() functions but am very new at jquery. Could someone give me a hint or explaining me what is going on? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi, you can try [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) image gallery or something similar, [carousel / image slider](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/06/jquery-slider.html)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer, i check the colorbox and the carousel but am a newcomer of jquery and i don't know how to make the effect of clicking the image and the open a div or sliding the window to the video reproduction. Could you tell more? any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Gabouh, if you need some help with your code, please ask a new question. For the start you can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UFtrK/109/ Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Stano, i already posted and i just integrated what you make, it has something of what i need, but when it loads the ajax it breaks my theme and load some text, how could i specify to load only images and plus inserting the images into the spot i made with jquery and turn it to a slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help. I already solved and this is the link: gist.github.com/uligo/6051675 if anyone find it useful or have a different solution, i would like to know it.